# set mysql connect to a php and access them from multiple php functions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php file, which connects to a mysql database 
using:

```
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
```

And on the same php, there are some functions that made use of that connection, and make querys...

I dont know how to set $mysqli to the entire php and call to it from functions, instead of repeating the connection on every function...

(I have 3 functions, i need to repeat the code of connection on every function, making at the end, 3 connections to the same database. I want to avoid that, and make one connection, and use it on the 3 functions without making another connection more.

Is there any way?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's got to be dupes, but here's two ways:

Pass it into the function:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$something = test($mysqli);

function test($conn) {
    mysqli_query($conn, 'stuff);
}
```

Or access the global variable:

```
function test() {
    mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'], 'stuff');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your function look like

```
 function something(){
    global $mysqli;
    // Rest of function
    }
```

This is just one way you can do this

Answer (score -1):

You can have a separate php module that "wraps" your mysqli calls.

```
function Sql_Query($query) {

$result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $query);
if (Sql_Check_Error($database_connection))
   dbg("Sql error in $query"); // Some debugging code
}
return $result;
```

}

Where Sql_Error_Check is yet another "wrapped" mysqli call, etc...

And this is a global.

```
$database_connection = Sql_Connect($database_host,$database_user,$database_password,$database_name);
```

There's an even better Object Oriented for mysqli.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: that calls the function on every query, that is even worst, you connect every time you do a query

Comment: My own code was actually very much like @AbraCadaver's - I over simplified it here to avoid having to explain where the GLOBAL was.